# How to detect similar videos

Tags: video, comparison, duplicate

I have a directory full of media. I would like to search similar videos and hand-remove certain copies (those that are too short, too long, have watermarks, don't have watermarks, &c.).

How can I find videos that are somewhat similar to each other?

Comment: I don't think you'll find such software (well, not for a low price anyway). OTOH there are duplicate file finder programs, you can check those out.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is [Digital Video Fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Content_Analysis).

Video fingerprinting is a technique in which software identifies, extracts and then compresses characteristic components of a video, enabling that video to be uniquely identified by its resultant “fingerprint”. Video fingerprinting is technology that has proven itself to be effective at identifying and comparing digital video data.

Here are some relevant companies that support this:

- [Advestigo (audio, video and image fingerprinting)](http://www.advestigo.com)
- [Attributor (image and video fingerprinting)](http://www.attributor.com/how_it_works/overview.php)
- [Audible Magic (audio & video image fingerprinting)](http://www.audiblemagic.com)
- [Auditude Connect technology (audio and video fingerprinting)](http://www.auditude.com)
- [Flingo (audio and video fingerprinting for Smart TV)](http://www.flingo.tv)
- [INA (video fingerprinting)](http://www.ina.fr/to-know-ina/signature.html)
- [iPharro Media (adaptive video fingerprinting)](http://www.ipharro.com)
- [Miranda (audio, video and image fingerprinting)](http://www.miranda.com)
- [Civolution (audio and video fingerprinting)](http://www.civolution.com)
- [Vercury (audio, image and video fingerprinting)](http://www.vercury.com)
- [Vidyatel Video conform, TV tracking and Management (frame accurate video fingerprinting)](http://www.vidyatel.com)
- [Vobile Content Identification and Management (audio and video fingerprinting)](http://www.vobileinc.com)
- [Yuvad Technologies - content-aware video advertising solution](http://www.yuvad.com)
- [YUVsoft (video fingerprinting and search)](http://yuvsoft.com/technologies/video_matching/)
- [Zeitera (video fingerprinting)](http://www.zeitera.com)
- [Lumilogic (video fingerprinting and search)](http://www.videomatching.eu)

All of these (which are listed on Wikipedia) seem professional paid solutions, some of them do no longer seem to exist. You might be able to find something by searching through project hosting websites...

Most of them decide to keep their algorithms private and rather provide a service than selling a product.

Answer (score 3):

I too have been looking for a program like this. The closest that I have found is Thumbsplus (Cerious.com). It can make thumbnails of most video types. It can then find duplicate or even similar thumbnails of these videos. It is really made for still photos, but it does work for this too.

It helped me.

Comment: A thumbnail compare method? That's actually pretty brilliant.

Comment: @music2myear: If and only if two similar videos generate a similar thumbnail. If one video if of a different FPS or starts a bit earlier/later, that might result in a completely different thumbnail.

Comment: Yes, it's bound to a lot of different variables. But it's probably very easy on system resources and given proper attention can result in a reasonably decent matching system that is less prone to differences in encoding or resolution.

Comment: @music2myear: Well, I would think it reduces the problem to detecting similar images. Which can still be complex if you want to do it at a proper level like Google Images and TinEye do. [idée](http://ideeinc.com/) is a starting point, which is the service used by TinEye. They do provide a free online service, but I doubt if it actually shows similar images by itself rather than just allowing one to find similar images when searching with an image.

Comment: If you could get it to generate multiple thumbnails for each video (maybe one per 30 seconds or so) that would probably work well.  (And then you're basically grabbing 1% of the frames ( typically 30 fps so 900 frames in 30 s)

Answer (score 2):

I found this little program, it's got a trail period, so you can give it a try. Then it cost $50

http://visualsearchpony.com/

but it works, uses fingerprinting tech, by making thumbs of videos.

Comment: The link now takes you to a blog.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Video Comparer (shareware).

http://www.video-comparer.com

It quickly detects similar videos with image transformations and supports split videos into multiple CDs.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to fingerprint the audio and find the videos that share a similar audio track.

AcoustId is open source and supports the generation of such audio fingerprints.

You can use fpcalc to generate a fingerprint from the audiotrack. AcoustId provides a small number seach engine called acoustid-index to search for similar fingerprints.

- https://bitbucket.org/acoustid/acoustid-index
- http://acoustid.org/

Answer (score 0):

One free and working program (detecting duplicate videos with the same content but different quality and size) we've managed to successfully use was [SimilarImages](https://tn123.org/simimages/). Although it's discontinued and really old, here are some tips to make it work on newer Windows versions: [SimilarImages Reviews - AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/similarimages/reviews/).

Answer (score 0):

a newer addition to this type of tool is i-DeClone, which fares very well against similar programs, both free and paid, to detect duplicate movies hiding in different file formats and resolutions, see for review:
https://www.zabkat.com/declone/best-duplicate-movie-files-software.htm#timing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).